# How to join second line to end of first line in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, join, replace, concatenation

I tried to read lines like below:

```
A:129    Tyr -P-   9    -          -               -               10xR,4xG,3xD,3xK,2xP,2xV,2xY,1xE,1xI,1xL,1xM,1xN,1
                                                                   xQ,1xT 
A:181    Ser -P-   8    -          -               -               9xR,9xS,8xG,4xT,3xD,3xL,3xQ,3xV,2xK,2xM,1xA,1xF,1x
                                                                   H,1xY  
A:50     His ---   9    -          -               -               17xL,9xA,4xK,3xI,3xR,3xV,2xN,2xS,1xC,1xE,1xH,1xQ,1
                                                                   xT
```

Where each Even lines is a continuation of ODD lines but which is split by "\n\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s" **so I want to replace those '\n\s(n)' to '' and join back to end of ODD lines .**

**FOR EXAMPLE:**

```
A:181    Ser -P-   8    -          -               -               9xR,9xS,8xG,4xT,3xD,3xL,3xQ,3xV,2xK,2xM,1xA,1xF,1x
                                                                   H,1xY
```

TO

```
A:181    Ser -P-   8    -          -               -               9xR,9xS,8xG,4xT,3xD,3xL,3xQ,3xV,2xK,2xM,1xA,1xF,1xH,1xY
```

CODE:

```
import os
import sys
import re

lines=["A:129    Tyr -P-   9    -          -               -               10xR,4xG,3xD,3xK,2xP,2xV,2xY,1xE,1xI,1xL,1xM,1xN,1","                                                                   xQ,1xT","A:181    Ser -P-   8    -          -               -               9xR,9xS,8xG,4xT,3xD,3xL,3xQ,3xV,2xK,2xM,1xA,1xF,1x","                                                                   H,1xY","A:50     His ---   9    -          -               -               17xL,9xA,4xK,3xI,3xR,3xV,2xN,2xS,1xC,1xE,1xH,1xQ,1","                                                                   xT"]

for i in lines:
     print i.replace("                                                                   ","")
```

Here,I just replaced spaces by empty space but i didnt get how to join those replaced EVEN lines to end of ODD lines.

So could some one help me to do the same.

Thanking you in advance.

**Hi guys , First of all Many more thanks for your kind replies. I tried all the ways but the followed one works correct:**

```
WILD= open("INPUT.txt", 'r')
merged = []
for line in WILD:
    if line.startswith(" "):
        merged[-1] += line.strip()
    else:
        merged.append(line.replace("\n",""))
```

OUTPUT:

```
A:129    Tyr -P-   9    -          -               -               10xR,4xG,3xD,3xK,2xP,2xV,2xY,1xE,1xI,1xL,1xM,1xN,1xQ,1xT
A:181    Ser -P-   8    -          -               -               9xR,9xS,8xG,4xT,3xD,3xL,3xQ,3xV,2xK,2xM,1xA,1xF,1xH,1xY
A:50     His ---   9    -          -               -               17xL,9xA,4xK,3xI,3xR,3xV,2xN,2xS,1xC,1xE,1xH,1xQ,1xT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the entire file as a single string, then replace the entire whitespace with a single tab:

```
filepointer = open("INPUT.txt")
text = filepointer.read()
text = re.sub(r"\n\s{20,}", "\t", text)
```

This matches and removes sequences of a newline followed by 20 *or more* spaces, replacing them with a tab. (That way I don't have to count the precise number of spaces, and the program still works if some lines are slightly different).
If you don't want a tab between the joined lines, just use a space (`" "`) instead of `"\t"`.

And if you must have the result as a list of lines, split `text` afterwards:

```
merged = text.splitlines()
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! Once you have solved your problem, don't forget to "accept" the answer that you found most useful, by clicking on the big check mark. You can also vote up all answers you found useful, too :-)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of that `replace` statement, you can just use [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to strip away whitespace at the beginning or the end of the string. Also, you can use `zip` to iterate pairs of lines.

```
for x, y in zip(l[::2],l[1::2]):
    print "".join([x, y.strip()])
```

Or use `next` to get the next line if this is an iterator, like a file.

```
for x in iterator:
    y = next(iterator)
    print "".join([x, y.strip()])
```

Both ways, all the even lines (0, 2, ...) go to `x` and all the odd ones (1, 3, ...) to `y`.
Of course, this is assuming that *all* the entries in the list/file are spanning exactly two lines.

If they can span an arbitrary number of lines (just one, or two, or maybe five), then this will get more complicated. In this case, you might try something like this:

```
merged = []
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith(" "):
        merged[-1] += line.strip()
    else:
        merged.append(line)
```

Note: If thoses are indeed lines from a file, you might have to apply `strip` to *all* the lines, i.e. also `x.strip()` and `merged.append(line.strip())`, as each line will be terminated by `\n` which you might want to get rid of.

Comment: Just as a note of caution, this does exactly what @user3805057 asked but if ever there was an instance where a line did not wrap in the input file this would cause get the rest of the joins of track.

Comment: That zip doesn't do what you think it does.  `l=[1,2,3,4,5,6]` . `zip(l, l[1:]) --> [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)] `.  Instead, `zip(l[::2],l[1::2])`